# how to combine multiple query into one single query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have three queries as below and I need to combine them into one. Does any body know how to do that?

```
select COUNT(*) from dbo.VWAnswer where questionId =2 and answer =1

select COUNT(*) from dbo.VWAnswer where questionId =3 and answer =4

select COUNT(*) from dbo.VWAnswer where questionId =5 and answer =2
```

I want to find out total count of those people whose `gender = 1 and Education = 4 and marital status = 2`

Following is the table columns(With one ex) that i refer:

```
questionId      questionText    anwser    AnserSheetID

  1              Gender           1           1

  2              Qualification    4           1

  3              Marital Status   2           1

  1              Gender           2           2

  2              Qualification    1           2

  3              Marital Status   2           2

  1              Gender           1           3

  2              Qualification    3           3

  3              Marital Status   1           3
```

Basically, these are questions answered by different people whose answers are stored in this table.

So if we consider above table entries I should get 1 as total count based upon above 3 conditions i.e. `gender = 1 and Education = 4 and marital status = 2`

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Can you please explain your second part of question. And also give the proper table structure.

Comment: Still your question is not clear. I have answered based on my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine your three count queries, you can try the below SQL to get it done.

```
select 
sum(case when questionId =2 and anwser=1 then 1 else 0 end) as FCount,
sum(case when questionId =3 and anwser=4 then 1 else 0 end) as SCount,
sum(case when questionId =5 and anwser=2 then 1 else 0 end) as TCount
from dbo.VWAnswer
```

Update 1:

```
select 
Sum(case when questionText='Gender' and anwser='1' then 1 else 0 end) as GenderCount,
Sum(case when questionText='Qualification' and anwser='4' then 1 else 0 end) as EducationCount,
Sum(case when questionText='Marital Status' and anwser='2' then 1 else 0 end) as MaritalCount
from VWAnswer
```

We can only get the counts based on the rows and every condition should apply in each row.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the `else 0` because nulls aren't summed, but yes this should work.

Comment: Am getting error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." ie.e because my answers column is nvarchar and if I modify the query like "sum(case when questionId =2 and ISNUMERIC(answer)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as FCount,
" AM getting total no of rows and not the correct count as per my where clause

Comment: @MANOJ GOPI I have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

You might use a joined view meeting you conditions and select the count of the rows fitting your conditions.

```
Select COUNT(*) as cnt from
(
   Select a.AnserSheetID
   from VWAnswer a
   Join VWAnswer b on a.AnserSheetID=b.AnserSheetID and b.questionId = 2 and b.anwser=4
   Join VWAnswer c on a.AnserSheetID=c.AnserSheetID and c.questionId = 3 and c.anwser=2
   where a.questionId=1 and a.anwser=1
) hlp
```